# The [lime] tag - unit testing or machine learning explanations?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

The [lime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lime) tag is intended for the [lime test framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lime_(test_framework)) but the majority of questions from 2016 onward are for the [Lime agnostic model explanation tool](https://github.com/marcotcr/lime).

I propose splitting into `[lime-unittest]` and `[lime-explanations]`.

Comment: Why not leave 'lime' for the ML usage and split off the test stuff to 'lime-unittest' or 'lime-testing-framework'? The test framework seems to be a dead project -- no contributions or releases in the past 11 years (which was an alpha version of a major release).

Comment: That could work too, it would certain mean fewer retags.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - but then, a couple of years from this, another project comes by and names itself "lime" or "lime-something", and we are back to square one :( Better to rename both to close the matter for good.

Comment: By that logic we should never have _any_ tags without a suffix indicating what exactly their purpose is. Nobody (or nearly nobody) is adding new questions about the test framework, so disambiguate that one to a more specific tag and let the modern usage have the primary.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - not necessarily. The problem here is that it *already* causes confusion. Renaming one and leaving the other just shifts the issue to the next time this happens. "Modern" usage will become "past" usage very soon, and someone else will have to repeat the same request with different inputs over and over. We have a chance to deal with it right here and now.

Comment: I think the confusion is mitigated by the fact that one library is, functionally, dead. The questions about the test framework are all older, and can be safely squirreled away to a distinctly disambiguated tag. The ML library can continue using the primary. _If_ at some point there's a new library/language/whatever called Lime -- well we can cross that bridge _if_ it ever gets built. This kind of "future proofing" for what-ifs is pretty much just a premature optimization.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - there is premature optimization and then there is programming (in our case - tagging) *defensively*. We *clearly* see a problem now and we are deciding to not do anything because what? Too much work? No, this is a single rename. I don't see any other reason.

Comment: And in the meantime people will continue using the lime base tag as they will (because they will; history has proven the necessity of a "blacklist" or equivalent). So not only will you need to manage the two disambiguated tags, but also incur the unending task of sorting the base tag. I firmly believe we should solve the problem we do have and not try to use our crystal balls to solve for those problems which may never be.

Comment: (also yes I know that "blacklist" is now considered not-PC, but i apologize: i don't know what we're calling it now)

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas - funny you mention that because *this* sounds like optimizing prematurely :) We have a problem at our hands: an ambiguous tag with two distinct usages. We split both usages and give them unambiguous naming - the problematic tag stops existing. We also shifted misused tag recreation to 1.5K rep (because you just can't create tags under the threshold). What's more, by *starting* with "lime-", we pretty much dealt with accidental creation, because there are autocompletion will suggest the tag instantly. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] P.s. You mention more work, but we already wasted more time on discussing why the second tag *should not* be changed than it takes to rename a tag.

Comment: While we're at it, we should probably change `javascript` to `javascript-programminglanguage`, just in case an unrelated hypothetical future project decides to name itself javascript and throws the current tagging scheme into disarray. ;)

Comment: @abeboparebop - I appreciate the irony :) However, despite being witty, the analogy is not applicable. There already is a problem that one project called itself Lime and then another decided to do the same. Since "lime" is already known to cause trouble, it should not be kept around without amendment.

Comment: I respect all opinions but I agree with @Roddy on this one.  If most people currently understand “lime” to refer to the machine learning library than we should allow it to have the main “lime” tag.  It’s only ambiguous if there are multiple projects with significant traction.